# Angular ng-model with Bootstrap Modal wont work twice

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say that there are 10 list of operators in table, and there's edit button for each operator. When I click edit for operator 1, the modal works fine with the operator data shown in input field, but when I close the modal and click the same operator, the modal shows but not the data by ng-model (empty value for input field). But if I click another operator, it shows the value.

In other word, it will work if:
click operator 1 -> close modal -> click operator 2 (work):
click operator 1 -> close modal -> click operator 2 -> close modal -> click operator 1 (work)

But will not work if:
click operator 1 -> close modal -> click operator 1 again (won't work)

I'm using the same modal and it's called by ng-click. Is this some kind of bug or I'm missing something? Thank you.

***Edit***
Here's my js script:

```
$("#company-modal form")[0].reset();

$("#company-modal form").attr("action", baseurl + "api/" + (company_id ? "update" : "insert") + "/company");

$("#company-modal").modal("show");

$scope.company = company_id ? $json(baseurl + "api/detail/company/" + company_id).message : {company_type : "trading"};
```

and here's one example for the input tag in modal:

```
<input ng-model="company.company_name" name="company_name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Comment: I think your problem is in line 1023. Seriously, how can we help you without seeing your code?

Comment: use a modal in angularjs way?. you can take UI Bootstrap.

Comment: Still not enough code, I am afraid. I need the controller and the $json function.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing exactly this problem, and I would confess that I haven't yet found the exact cause of the issue. **However I have found one workaround** which will surly achieve the ultimate objective. Just use `value="{{company.company_name}}"` inside your input tag, and it would work as per your expectation.

Comment: Just to add, I can understand why it is difficult to give working jsfiddle code sample for this issue, because if you will try to reproduce this issue by a dummy code, it won't work, you won't be able to reproduce! In my own application, at one place it is working perfectly fine, and at all other places, it is completely failing to show values on 2nd opening onward, and I can't figure out what is the difference between the two cases!! I will keep you posted as I find more on this issue. Just in case, you have found the exact cause, please let me know.

Comment: Hello shanti, I've figured the cause, it's because I didn't use ng-bind, so in the input tag there must be an ng-bind attribute, after that no matter how many I open and close the modal the value will bind automatically.

Comment: Is ng-bind really doing the work for you!! Because it didn't work for me. Also, it isn't the real cause though I think. ng-model is supposed to do two-way binding, so if ng-model is there we shouldn't need anything else for data binding. There is something else which is causing the issue, so a temporary workaround is to use ng-bind for textarea tags, and value="{{}}" for input tags.

Comment: yes, ng-bind and ng-value works fine with me, value={{}} also works but I prefer ng-value for cleaner looks